# Sending Compiled bytecode of gremlin query to remote server

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Example Code(JAVA):

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.open(yml.getFile());
DriverRemoteConnection driver = DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "graph_traversal");
GraphTraversalSource allGraph = AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal().withRemote(driver);

//Compile Script
GremlinScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();
String script = "graph_traversal.V().outE().inV().path().unfold().dedup().group().by{\"category\"}";
SimpleBindings bind = new SimpleBindings();
GraphTraversal compiled = (GraphTraversal)engine.eval(script, bind);

//Send bytecode to remote server
CompletableFuture<RemoteTraversal<?, Object>> result = driver.submitAsync(compiled.asAdmin().getBytecode());
result.get(); // Exception
```

I'm trying to send a gremlin bytecode to remote server through driver.

But the codes occurs an exception when the script includes 'lamda'.

The exception message is as following.

Exception:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: An error occurred during serialization of this request [RequestMessage{, requestId=84d5d022-1b08-41a6-b57f-8fdc3b5b6c65, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[..., dedup(), unfold(), dedup(), group(), by(Script1$_run_closure1@78b612c6)]], aliases={g=graph_traversal}}}] - it could not be sent to the server - Reason: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler.class);
```

if the script doesn't contain the lambda, it won't make any exception.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: The use of `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` in this case confuses me a bit so as to not be able to answer your question properly. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve a bit more?

Comment: @stephenmallette because Driver only supports submit method for bytecode. and I have to build the bytecode from some string.

Comment: I'm glad you have your solution but I'm still not sure I follow. You can certainly submit string-based Gremlin through the driver (not just bytecode) and if you've already established `allGraph ` why not just directly do `allGraph.V().outE().inV().path().unfold().dedup()...` ?

Comment: Because I have to build gremlin query with Strings from external system.

Comment: And I have to manipulate them with variables in certain conditions.

Comment: For example... querying to partition A, B, or All.

Comment: Strings from External : ```"graphVar.V().blahQueries.group().by(groupingMethodFromExternal)" ``` I have to adjust graphVar and groupingMethodFromExternal under some condition to make complete gremlin query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
By using Lambda.Methods.